# Return file content in json encoding

Tags: php, json, rest

I have a txt file with this structure:

```
17/02/2016 [info] "hello"
17/02/2016 [debug] "world"
```

now I'm trying to read it with:

```
$fh = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");

while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
     echo json_encode($line);
}
fclose($fh);
```

the file is readed correctly but, in my chrome extension for try Rest API I get in the json tab:

> unexpected string

the raw structure is this:

```
"17/02/2016 [info] "hello" \rn""17/02/2016 [debug] "world" \rn...
```

how I can return each line in json content? I want to this for have a better organization in a response.

Comment: That raw structure you provided will never encode as JSON... because its not JSON formatted: http://www.json.org/

Comment: I kow it's raw... But I want encode each line in json for avoid the error : `unexpected string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can parse the input if you have the same string structure in your file and you create an array or object with your fields (date, info, text) and encode the array or object using json you can check for example `preg_match` for each line and use a regex to get the line structure into an array or object and at the end you can send your array of object or array of array as encoded json.
you can use a regex like this `([0-9]*\/[0-9]*\/[0-9]*)\s+\[([^\]]*)\]\s*\"([^\"]*)"` and get your information from each line

Comment: Uhm I have actually fixed creating an array, use `array_push` and at the end return the array in json encoding